How to Upload a 180-Degree Panoramic Video to YouTube with Limited Panning
I'm trying to upload a 180-degree panoramic video to YouTube so that viewers can pan left and right within a 180-degree range, but not all the way around (not a full 360-degree view). I also want to limit vertical panning, as looking up and down isn't necessary for my content (at least not very much).
Most of what I find online are tutorials for VR and fully 360-degree spherical videos.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Using VSDC Free Video Editor:
I exported the video with the following settings:

Embed 3D video information: Selected "Video is not stereoscopic."
Embed 360 video information: Chose "Equirectangular."

However, when I upload the video to YouTube, it allows viewers to pan a full 360 degrees, which isn't what I want.

Injecting Metadata with Spatial Media Metadata Injector:
I attempted to use the command-line tool to inject metadata that would limit the field of view to 180 degrees. Unfortunately, the arguments to set the FOV don't seem to exist.  The GUI for it is very limited.


My goal: I want YouTube to recognize my video as a 180-degree panoramic video, allowing viewers to pan only within the intended range horizontally and restrict unnecessary vertical panning.
Questions:

How can I properly configure my video and metadata so that YouTube limits the panning to 180 degrees horizontally?
Is there a way to adjust the metadata or use a different tool to achieve this effect?
Has anyone successfully uploaded a monoscopic 180-degree video to YouTube with these panning limitations?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
